# Spring Integration Suppressing Exceptions while splitting over iterator

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-dsl

Take for instance the following scenario:
I split a message over an Iterator. If an exception is thrown inside a `.handle()` while iterating over an element, all the remaining elements are skipped and the next message is obtained.
I need to suppress any possible exceptions so that all elements in the iterator are processed.

Since I am using Iterator instead of List, for instance, I cannot solve this using `.aggregate()`.

Please, how can I manage to get the desired behaviour...?

- Spring Boot Starter Integration 1.3.0
- Spring Integration 4.2.1
- Java DSL 1.1.1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just place `.channel(c -> c.executor(...))` after `.split()`.

In this case all your messages will be processed in parallel (at least) and all the downstream errors will be wrapped into `ErrorMessage` and sent to the `errorChannel` (by default).